# sci-kit learn: KNeighborsClassifier - Population matrix vs. Class labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to trying to get the class labels corresponding to the k Nearest Neighbors. Going through the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier) for KNeighborsClassifier, the predict() function returns the **Class labels for each data sample**, and the kneighbors() function returns **Indices of the nearest points in the population matrix**.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
X_train = [[1.0,2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0]]
y_train = ['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'test']
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=8)
neigh.fit(x_train, y_train)    
X_test = [[3.0, 3.0]]


>>> neigh.predict(xtest)
array(['Hello'], dtype='<U5')
>>> neigh.kneighbors(xtest)
(array([[1. , 2.23606798]]), array([[1, 0]]))
```

I want to get the **class labels for the k Nearest Neighbors**. What is the relationship between the population matrix and the class labels as specified in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question:

> What is the relationship between the population matrix and the class
>   labels as specified in the docs?

The answer is there is a one-to-one correspondence between the elements of the population matrix and the class labels. The first label corresponds to the first element of the population matrix, the second label to the second element and so on. For instance you have the following relationship in your example:

```
[1.0, 2.0] <-> 'Hello'
[2.0, 3.0] <-> 'this'
[4.0, 5.0] <-> 'is'
[6.0, 7.0] <-> 'test'
```

So if you want to get the class labels for the k Nearest Neighbors you can use the `kneighbors` function. From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors), the function returns:

> dist : array Array representing the lengths to points, only present if
>   return_distance=True
>
> ind : array Indices of the nearest points in the population matrix.

The idea is to use the `ind` array to get the class labels, like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X_train = [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0]]
y_train = ['Hello', 'this', 'is', 'test']
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=8)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_test = [[3.0, 3.0]]

prediction = neigh.predict(X_test)
distances, indices = neigh.kneighbors(X_test)

print([y_train[i] for i in indices[0]])
```

**Output**

```
['this', 'Hello']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, neigh.kneighbors(xtest) returns two values. The first array you obtained is a list of distances to the two nearest neighbors. Second one is indices of the neighbors in the training dataset.

```
neigh.kneighbors(xtest)
(array([[1. , 2.23606798]]), array([[1, 0]]))
```

You can simply get the label of these indices from **y_train**.

```
dist,indices = neigh.kneighbors(xtest)
for item in indices[0]:
  print y_train[item]
```